# What does this block mean in Swift - Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

This is a code block in Alamofire/Manager.swift:

- It is inside a class named "public class Manager"

---

```
public static let sharedInstance: Manager = {
    let configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = Manager.defaultHTTPHeaders

    return Manager(configuration: configuration)
}()
```

---

Obviously, this is "let something equals the closure," but what I don't get is what does the "()" in the end of the line mean?

To defer the execution of the code? How? (It seems to me that the execution won't be deferred as it has the "()"? And I am wondering why this is not causing the existing of a memory circle? It returns the Manger itself and the returned new instance will also do the same, returning a new self...

Why not a key word "lazy"?

I have a strange feeling that i've seem this usage somewhere else too. I'm learning Swift for 60 days now. Am I fast or slow? How to be a iOS developer also?(I mean how to be a real one, not enroll the program)

For now I'm kind of confused and reading all the source code I could get. Sometimes I feel the official docs and Xcode sucks and I don't know how to read a source code scratch. Any tips and advice?

Comment: Re: learning iOS development - Stanford University has **free** (and quality) video courses for learning [Swift](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099) and [Objective C](https://itunes.apple.com/en/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550)

Comment: @IslamQ.    I've already taken the #Stanford courses and I think it is relatively too easy..  On the other hand I have encountered countless issues(no problems when i learn python), including how to design a icon for app, and the icons for too bar items. & custom views and animation. how 2 read the official guides for old APIs that do not exist with Xcode 6.3. Just helpless.

Comment: Then have you checked [raywenderlich.com](http://raywenderlich.com) and other tutorial websites to learn different tricks?
Also, what I found really helpful is by actually creating an app... you'll learn whatever is relevant to your needs on the go...

Comment: @IslamQ. Thank you for the advice. I'll try them. Just find that I may also need a second display ...  developing an App.

Answer (score 0):

This initializes `sharedInstance` with the result of the closure (without the parens at the end it would just initialize it to the closure itself)  It's a standard syntax for initializing variable with an initializer too complex for a simple expression.  In this multiple statements are required so that the `HTTPAdditionalHeaders` can be initialized.

Comment: So the const sharedInstance will be a instance of a new Manager class. That's no problem.

Comment: But the new instance of Manger will also have this property called sharedInstance, and it will be a new instance of Manger. This instance will also have the sharedInstance, it will then have a new instance.. this will not end.?

Comment: Thank u. .. I think i should try read all the source code files first and use the debug tool.

Comment: The "static" keyword used before a variable declaration flags the variable as a class (or type) variable and not an instance variable.  Hence there is a single copy of it shared by all instances of the class or type.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've made a mistake. The trick lies that the sharedInstance used a key word "static" This is common, but in python, which I am most familiar with, do not use this key word.

According to the official guide:

“You can also define properties that belong to the type itself, not to any one instance of that type. There will only ever be one copy of these properties, no matter how many instances of that type you create. These kinds of properties are called type properties.”

Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language”. iBooks. https://itun.es/cn/jEUH0.l

Answer (score 0):

the answer is at the session name "Setting a Default Property Value with a Closure or Function": https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID231